2012 Chevy Malibu brake light issue
2012 Chevy Malibu LT 2.4L has no brake lights. When the engine is off, the rear hazards are dim. Engine on and there is no lights in the back. Remove one sided pig tail, the other gets brighter. I've checked fuses, relays. There is power to the socket. It has a new battery, alternator, throttle body, brake pedal position sensor. None of these solved the issue. What else could be the issue?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
